# Extension got rejected 3 times and I don't understand why

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-web-store

My CRX got rejected yesterday because I did not comply with following section of our policy: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/program_policies#chrome_apps

- Require a local executable, other than the Chrome runtime, to run.
- Provide a webview of a website that is not owned or administered by you.
- Download or execute scripts dynamically outside a sandboxed environment such as a webview or a sandboxed iframe.
- Misuse notifications by sending spam, ads, promotions of any kind, phishing attempts, or unwanted messages in general.

  The extension was working fine for years. It uses native messaging to communicate with an executable.

The support is so slow to answer and still answering generic stuff that don't really apply to my work.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You call it an extension but you link to a policy page about apps. So if it really is an extension, that should be the first thing to point out to support.

Comment: I can't post a link because it's no longer exists one since google has removed my extension.